# Running a dotnet dll from process in a dotnet application on Linux

Tags: c#, process

I have a dotnet core 3.1 web application that takes the file path and exe and runs it, but made the switch to dotnet core as want to make use of the cross platform capabilities.

Application is working on Windows based environments using `Proocess.Start()` I've tried changing the extention of the environmental variable.

Windows code:

```
var process = await Task.Run(() =>
        Process.Start($"{path}/{file}");
```

When running on a linux box I get `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): Exec format error`
if I change the file to `.dll` extension from `.exe` which won't run, I don't think Wine is an option.

How can I achieve this through C# or does it need to call a wrapper sript?

**UPDATE**

Both the exe and dll are built from a dotnet core application using the same 3.1, the code currently working with below:

```
                var information = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    FileName = Path.Join(this.path, this.file),
                };

var process = await Task.Run(() =>
                        Process.Start(information));
```

The error I get on my Linux box:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): Exec format error    at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename,
> String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin,
> Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean
> setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32&
> stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal,
> Boolean throwOnNoExec)

Comment: A few things, you might want to use Path.Join (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=netcore-3.1) in order to make sure the path you reference in code is cross-platform compatible, regardless of OS. You might also want to look into building for a target runtime environment. If publishing for linux, you should not get a .exe output. Scott Hanselman made a great blog about how to do this (https://www.hanselman.com/blog/selfcontained-net-core-applications)

Comment: Ah thank you for this, I like the idea of the path being cross platform compatible, the application I'm trying to run is not my own but does come with both dll and exe for either environment.

Comment: So what is that application which you try to run? Is it also .net core application?

Comment: It is also a dotnet core application, if Windows it'll run the exe supplied, if Linux it'll run the dll within the same path.

Comment: You need to run it via dotnet: "dotnet PathToYour.dll" (assuming dotnet binary is in path). So in your case it would be `Filename = "dotnet", Arguments = Path.Join(this.path, this.file)`. If dotnet is not in path, then find where it is and use absolute path (usually "/usr/bin/dotnet")

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to pass in additional arguments though? Something like `Arguments = $"{Path.Join(this.path, this.file)} {someVar}"`

Comment: Pass them after the path to dll. So `Filename = "dotnet", Arguments = Path.Join(this.path, this.file) + " -myArg1 1 -myArg2 2"` and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exe file you have is likely Windows executable, and as such cannot be run on linux.

The .dll file you have is not an executable, so you cannot just start it via `Process.Start` directly. It is however can be started (assuming it has entry point) via "dotnet" application, which should be in path on your linux server already if you have .NET core framework installed there. If not present in path - it's usually located at /usr/bin/dotnet. If .NET core is not installed - [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux) it first. Then .dll can be run via:

```
dotnet PathToYour.dll
```

Your code then becomes:

```
var information = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = "dotnet",
    Arguments = Path.Join(this.path, this.file)
};
```

If you have arguments to pass, then append them after dll path:

```
    Arguments = Path.Join(this.path, this.file) + " " + "your arguments here"
```

Note that you can also run .dll the same way on windows, assuming .NET core framework is installed on target machine, because "dotnet.exe" is also present on windows and works the same.